# Trailing slash on Directory directive in httpd

Tags: httpd

Is there any difference between these configurations:

```
<Directory /var/www>
.....
</Directory>
```

and

```
<Directory /var/www/>
.....
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Negative, there should be no difference although the former should defined be preferred to comply with Apache's documented preference for this form. For other directives such as DocumentRoot and Location it *will* make a difference, so you should always refrain from using  the trailing slash in apache configs.