# What difference does slash make in apache2.conf?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

The default apache2.conf contains this:

```
<Directory /usr/share>
...
<Directory /var/www/>
```

Why is there a trailing slash in one but not in the other directive? What difference does it make?

Side question: If I do not want to share anything from */usr/share*, can I simply delete this part or set it to *Require all denied*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to the trailing slash, as: https://serverfault.com/a/263219 states, the argument to a [`Directory`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) directive must be directory path. Without a slash is the convention but either syntax is valid and has the same result.

Note that in other scenario's and in combination with other directives there may be differences, for example disabling the [`DirectorySlash`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive may result in  requests for `http://www.example.com/directory-path` getting different results displayed compared to the request for `http://www.example.com/directory-path/`

> If I do not want to share anything from /usr/share, can I simply delete this part or set it to Require all denied?

Directory statements themselves do not make any content public.
(AFAIK Only the  `[Script]Alias`  and `DocumentRoot` directives  and  similar map  URI paths to the file system.)
Directory blocks only apply specific settings to locations on a file system.  That means that you can leave directory blocks like the one for for `/usr/share` even when you don't share  content from there (yet). That does not have any security or performance impact.